# How do I append to a table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of:

```
foo = []
foo << "bar"
foo << "baz"
```

I don't want to have to come up with an incrementing index. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The entire documentation is available at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/

Comment: oh that's really helpful. google kept pointing me towards http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html which is basically useless.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You are looking for the `insert` function, found in the `table` section of the main library.

```
foo = {}
table.insert(foo, "bar")
table.insert(foo, "baz")
```

Comment: Exactly. You don't need the semicolons either, but you can have em if you want to.

Comment: @rsethc Two 'duplicate' answers were bound to be posted at the same moment sometime in Stack Overflow's history (and I bet we won't be the last to, either). To be fair I did add some information about memory/time savings.

Answer (score 72):

```
foo = {}
foo[#foo+1]="bar"
foo[#foo+1]="baz"
```

This works because the `#` operator computes the length of the list. The empty list has length 0, etc.

If you're using Lua 5.3+, then you can do almost exactly what you wanted:

```
foo = {}
setmetatable(foo, { __shl = function (t,v) t[#t+1]=v end })
_= foo << "bar"
_= foo << "baz"
```

Expressions are not statements in Lua and they need to be used somehow.

Comment: It's slightly fast than `table.insert`.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the `__shl` function returns `self`, pushed could be chained, e.g. `_= foo << "bar" << "baz"`

Answer (score 16):

I'd personally make use of the `table.insert` function:

```
table.insert(a,"b");
```

This saves you from having to iterate over the whole table therefore saving valuable resources such as memory and time.